# Multiselect value into a table

Tags: forms, multi-selection

*I apologize in advance if I am unable to explain this requirement more efficiently.*

**The context:**

User is creating a client Profile. First option is to select of type account. User can either select one or more than one account types.

**The task:**

User can select one or two account types by clicking on multi-select list.
Once the user clicks on any list items in multi-select, it will move to right. In addition, blank input fields will appear where user can manually enter data. 
User can manually enter data and click on save. Once saved, a table will appear below that will have summarized view. Table will only have one row.

**Question:**

- **Do you foresee any problem with this approach?**
- **If you do see a problem, any alternative solution?**

**Proposed mockup:**
[image: account profile mockup]

User can view details and all the information added in another section of the same form. My only concern in initial part. Do you guy see any problem with this approach?

Comment: I'm a little unclear about how you get from step two to step three. Where does the information come from, and what does the information in step two have to do with the table at the bottom?

Comment: Step 1 > select account type. Step 2 > input number of accounts and currency. Step 3 > Click save.                                                       Even if the user selects all account types and clicks save. Only one row will appear in the table.Purpose of the table below is to give summarized view in a table format. I apologize if i am still unclear. It is a little tricky requirement.

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking at your columns in step two, and they don't match up with the columns in step three. So, I guess my question is, where do you get the data to populate the table at the bottom just based on information the user put in in step two?

Comment: That information is system driven. This is only one part of the form at later stage. Record is already in the system. At this stage it is bring reviewed by the checker for compliance. They need to manually enter number of accounts and currency type for each country appendix. User will have to fill out this same form for each country appendix. Not fun!

Comment: Gotta be honest, I just can't wrap my head around the process, so I would be hesitant to throw out any ideas.

Comment: Ok here is a refined mockup. May be this would help. http://goo.gl/axPzmI When I got this requirement, even I was scratching my head. Thank you either way. :)

Comment: How many accounts does user typically have?

Comment: There is no cap on user accounts. So there is a potential that user may have a large number of accounts ( transaction and non-transaction )over time. But type of accounts is a fixed number.

Comment: One thing that is visually difficult to parse is that you have a list-builder device, leading to a table builder, which after Save, looks like it ends in a static table. If you can simplify the list builder, I'm assuming the Save command will populate a table row at the top of the table, otherwise in a potentially long table, the user will have no clear indication of success. you could have as well a simple visual device, such as how comments work here; a flashing yellow fade on the newly created asset. Basecamp by 37 signals does this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think current interaction flow could be significantly increased, as it looks rather complex now. You could get the idea from the picture below. The features are:

- **Clear interface, which supports smooth flow**. The flow assumes sequental adding account type and setting its parameters. Then this step is repeated for another account type. So each step is focused on a sertain account type.
- **Clear "Add account type" option** instead of weird arrows between multi-select control and table rows.
- **Smart multi-select control behavior**, which displays accounts type which were not selected yet.

[image]